# Present Relationship between 3 entities in ER model

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

I'm a newbie in Database Design. Sorry if the question is stupid.

From the requirement specification. I identified entities: Applicant, University, Condition, Offer.

And the relationship between these are:
- Applicant apply University.
- university interview Applicant.
- University make Offer.
- University offer Applicant.
- Applicant accept Offer.
- Offer belong to Applicant.
- University has Condition.

I have designed the ER like this:

I have no clue is it ok? I very appreciate your help. :)

Here is the brief of the requirement specification:

*Applicants may apply to five different universities. Each university may or may not interview the applicant and then **may make an offer to the applicant**. The offer may be conditional or unconditional. If the offer is conditional, then the conditions are stored and communicated to the student. The applicant needs to decide which of the conditional offers he or she wishes to accept, up to a maximum of three. If the condition is met when the results come out at the end of the year, the offer becomes unconditional and applicants then may accept one of the unconditional offers.*

- Update: New ER design
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8Yl2.png)
- Or may be this one is better
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yhzJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

I see a few issues.

1. The specification says `The offer may be conditional or unconditional.`  However, you modeled conditions as belonging to a university, rather than to an offer.
2. It also says `the conditions are stored and communicated to the student`, but I see no association between Conditions and Applicants.
3. You also listed `University make Offer` and `Offer belong to Applicant` separately from `University offer Applicant`, but I believe this is a case of a relationship turned entity, in other words I see an Offer as a many-to-many relationship between Universities and Applicants which has dependent attributes and Conditions.

Comment: I've followed the steps in the "Database System" book. As the result, I have this design. But I don't know how to present the relationship "Applicant can only accept one unconditional offer", but "Can accept maximum 3 conditional offers". The new design at the updated post. Hope you can take a look! Thank you so much.